# Symfony3 Error manipulating time duration with doctrine

Tags: time, doctrine-orm, symfony

I want to use a variable time as the amount of time passed to do something:

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="TempsPasse", type="time", nullable=true)
 */
public $tempsPasse;
```

Code:

```
$Information->setTempsPasse(new \DateTime($Log->getTempsPasse()->format('H:i:s')));
$Information->setTempsPasse(clone($Log->getTempsPasse()));//Same result
$Information->setTempsPasse(new \DateTime('01:00:00'));//Same result
```

Where `echo($Log->getTempsPasse()->format('H:i:s'));` show: 01:00:00

Then when I flush I get this error:

> FatalErrorException in TimeType.php line 53: Error: Call to a member
>   function format() on a non-object

Where am I wrong and how can I handle time with doctrine ?

EDIT

---

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="TempsPasse", type="time")
 */
public $tempsPasse;


/**
 * Set tempsPasse
 *
 * @param \DateTime $tempsPasse
 *
 * @return Log
 */
public function setTempsPasse($tempsPasse)
{
    $this->tempsPasse = $tempsPasse;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get tempsPasse
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getTempsPasse()
{
    return $this->tempsPasse;
}
```

That's the same code for both entities.

Comment: Can we see your Entity code for the $Log object? And in particular, the method `getTempsPasse()`.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I've edit.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this works:

```
$Information->setTempsPasse( new \DateTime($Log->getTempsPasse()) );
```

The new \DateTime may be expecting a DateTime object...
Otherwise, can you edit your post and show how you create the $Log object first, and the code leading up to that.

The one thing I'm thinking is when you create the new \DateTime it is expecting line this:

```
new \DateTime( '01:00:00' )
```

Notice the quotes around the time parameter.

Comment: Without the ->format it won't work. The Log DateTime is set with a form and works well. If I do $Information->setTempsPasse(clone($Log->getTempsPasse())); I get the same result.

Comment: In fact the problem is not to set the variable with a DateTime, but that doctrine understand that's a Time value enven with the right format...